# How to get the current iteration of the Enumerable.Repeat method

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable

Having this code:

```
   return Enumerable.Repeat<MyClass>(new MyObject
   {   
     Iteration = // Get the current loop index 
   },
   10).ToList<MyClass>();

   public MyClass
   {
     public int Iteration {get;set;}
   }
```

How can I set the current loop index in the property `Iteration` by using the `Enumerable.Repeat` method?

Comment: note that Enumerable.Repeat() is used to return the same object n times.  It looks like you want to create a new object 10 times.

Comment: Yes, I do. But with a different value.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable.Range`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx) instead:

```
int count = 10;
List<MyObject> objects =  Enumerable.Range(0, count)
     .Select(i => new MyObject { Iteration = i })
     .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the ordinal of the current item, one way is to use the `Select` [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) that exposes an index. You can then create something like an anonymous type to hold the contents of the original enumerable (in this case, your `Repeat` result) and the index:

```
var repeats = Enumerable.Repeat("Something", 10).Select((s, i) => new { s, i });

foreach (var rep in repeats)
    Console.WriteLine(rep.i + rep.s);
```

Prints:

```
0Something
1Something
...
9Something
```

I'm not sure what you'd need this for. If it's just to create a list of objects, then Tim's alternative would be better suited (though in theory this would also work).